# same program gives different outputs everytime I run

Tags: c++, input, output, max, min

I tried writing a program that outputs "YES" whether every x value or y value is all the same. Otherwise it gives the output "NO". The logic is, if all the x values maximum value is the same as the all the x values minimum value, than this value has never changed, hence all the x values are the same. Same for the y values.

However, the output sometimes give the correct result, sometimes not (for the same input). Moreover, the outputs are not regular. (For example, 2 correct, 3 wrong, 5 correct, 1 wrong etc.)

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n;
    int minX,minY=INT_MAX;
    int maxX,maxY=INT_MIN;
    cin>>n;
    while(n--){    //for the next n line
        int x,y;
        cin>>x>>y;
        maxX=max(maxX,x);
        //cout<<maxX<<" ";    //comments I write to find out what the heck is happening

        minX=min(minX,x);    // This value changes irregularly, which I suspect is the problem.
        //cout<<minX<<" ";

        maxY=max(maxY,y);
        //cout<<maxY<<" ";

        minY=min(minY,y);
        //cout<<minY<<endl;

    }
    if(maxX==minX||maxY==minY){    //If the x values or the y values are all the same, true
        cout<<"YES";
    }
    else{
        cout<<"NO";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
5
0 1
0 2
0 3
0 4
0 5
```

Output when it Works (with the couts I commented):

```
0 0 1 1
0 0 2 1
0 0 3 1
0 0 4 1
0 0 5 1
YES
```

One of the output when it doesn't work(with the couts I commented)

```
0 -1319458864 1 1   // Not all the wrong outputs are the same, each wrong output is different than the other wrong output.
0 -1319458864 2 1
0 -1319458864 3 1
0 -1319458864 4 1
0 -1319458864 5 1
NO
```

Comment: Why do you use soooooo many includes that you don't use?

Comment: You never initialize `minX` and `maxX`.

Comment: ^ Which means that reading them leaves your program with undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these lines

```
int minX,minY=INT_MAX;
int maxX,maxY=INT_MIN;
       ^
```

`minX` and `maxX` is **never** initialized. This is an UB as defined by the standard. Whatever you read is not predictable - it's usually what'l left on that block of memory by another process.

Do note that `=` has a higher priority than comma, so the expression is evaluated as

```
int (minX),(minY=INT_MAX);
```

Actually the comma has the lowest priority among all operators in C++. Change them to these should fix

```
int minX=INT_MAX,minY=INT_MAX;
int maxX=INT_MIN,maxY=INT_MIN;
         ^~~~~~~
```

Comment: Placing one variable (with initialization) per line will also fix the issue.